# Unable to download excel in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-view

I am trying to download a excel file on click of a button. But i am facing error

```
IOERROR : [ERRNO13] Permission Denied on "Test.xlsx"
```

Here is what i am trying to do.

```
<button name="fetch_invoice" attrs="{'invisible':[('show_transaction_specific_fields', '=', False)]}" type="object" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm o_list_button_add"  string="Download Invoice"/>


@api.multi
def fetch_invoice(self):
    attachment_id, file_name = self.create_excel_file()
    base_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('amgl.live.url')
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url': base_url + '/web/content/%s/%s'%(attachment_id, file_name),
            'target': 'self'
        }

def create_excel_file(self):
    file_name = 'Test.xlsx'
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_name)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')
    workbook.close()
    attachment = self.add_file_in_attachment(file_name)
    attachment_id = attachment.id
    return attachment_id, file_name

   def add_file_in_attachment(self, file_name):
    byte_data = 0
    with open(file_name, "rb") as xlfile:
        byte_data = xlfile.read()
    attachment = self.env['ir.attachment'].create({'name': file_name,
                                                   'datas': base64.b64encode(byte_data),
                                                   'datas_fname': file_name,
                                                   'res_model': 'res.users',
                                                   'res_id': 1, }
```

Now when i click button and try to fetch the excel report it gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 638, in 
 _handle_exception
 return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
 result = self._call_function(**self.params)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 331, in 
_call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in 
 wrapper
  return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 324, in 
 checked_call
   result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
  return self.method(*args, **kw)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 504, in 
 response_wrap
  response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist- 
  packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", 
 line 889, in call_button
 action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", 
 line 877, in _call_kw
  return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
 return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 672, in 
 call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/allshore/AMARK/amgl/models/reports.py", line 73, in 
fetch_transaction_invoice
attachment_id, file_name = self.create_excel_file(start_date, end_date)
 File "/home/allshore/AMARK/amgl/models/reports.py", line 404, in 
create_excel_file
book.save(file_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", 
line 367, in save
save_workbook(self, filename)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 
 282, in save_workbook
archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Test.xlsx'
```

Comment: This error occurs in linux only

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a file in a directory when you don't have the permission. Added the write permission to this directory.
Use **sudo chmod +w**